# PHP how to delete deep keys programmatically

Tags: php

Imagine you have a deep array like this:

```
<?php 
$array = ['hello' => ['deep' => 'treasure']];
```

Then you had an array of the keys to access the string 'treasure'

```
['hello', 'deep'];
```

How do you delete the string treasure if you did not know the depth of the array till run time

Edit:

My apologises I've definitely not provided enough information for what I'm looking to achieve

Here is some code I've come up with which does what I need but uses unsafe eval (keep in mind the target destination could be an array so array_walk_recursive won't work)

```
function iterator_keys($iterator, $outer_data) {
  $keys = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $iterator->getDepth() + 1; $i++) {
    $sub_iterator = $iterator->getSubIterator($i);
    $keys[$i] = ($i == 0 && is_object($outer_data)
      || $i > 0 && is_object($last_iterator->current())) ?
    '->{"' . $sub_iterator->key() . '"}' :
    '["' . $sub_iterator->key() . '"]';
    $last_iterator = $sub_iterator;
  }
  return $keys;
}
function recursive_filter($data, callable $selector_function, $iterator = NULL) {
  $iterator = $iterator ?? new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
  );
  foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($selector_function($value, $key, $iterator)) {
      eval('unset($data' . implode('', iterator_keys($iterator, $data)) . ');');
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

The intention is to have a deep data structure a function that evalutes each node and if it matches a condition then remove it from the data structure in place, if this can be done without eval that would be amazing but so far I think PHP can't programmatically delete something that is more than one level deep

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` or write custom recursive function - this will be faster

Comment: desired output is to have the string treasure removed from the array but consider that you do not know it's depth till run time so 

unset($array['hello']['deep']); 

is not valid because it requires knowing the data structure ahead of time



array_walk_recursive could work here I think

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: I realised I didn't write my question out correctly and didn't have time to update it, I'll post what I came up with as a solution to see if it helps people understand what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think what you want is somethings like this

```
<?php    
$array = ['hello' => ['deep' => ['deep1' => 'treasure']]];
$keys = ["hello", "deep", "deep1"];

function remove_recursive(&$array, $keys, $level = 0)
{
    if ($level >= count($keys)) {
        return $array;
    }
    if (isset($array[$keys[$level]]) && $level == count($keys) - 1) {
        unset($array[$keys[$level]]);
    } elseif (isset($array[$keys[$level]])) {
        $array[$keys[$level]] = remove_recursive($array[$keys[$level]], $keys, $level + 1);
    }

    return $array;
}

var_dump(remove_recursive($array, $keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this really quick and dirty way that uses eval to achieve your goal:

```
$array = ['hello' => ['deep' => 'treasure']];
$keys = ['hello', 'deep'];

$expression = 'unset($array[\'' . implode('\'][\'', $keys) . '\']);';
eval($expression);
```

But maybe you can tell us more about your development and we can help you reorganize it somehow to avoid this problem at all.

Comment: Very dirty. Only use this if you know that `$keys` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the target array element to `null`.  Optionally you could use `''`:

```
$array = ['hello' => ['deep' => 'treasure']];
$path  = ['hello', 'deep'];

$temp = &$array;

foreach($path as $key) {
    $temp =& $temp[$key];
}
$temp = null;

print_r($array);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [hello] => Array
        (
            [deep] =>
        )

)
```